# On change Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In My previous Code i have four Loan type 
  its all type  radio button

1. Conv.
2. FHA
3. VA
4. USDA

and I have one input fields downpayment
when i change four type loan type values change down payment 
 LINk:[Site URl](http://www.truemortgagecalculator.com/)

When i change this design UI  [MY Site url](http://dotnetportfolio.com/project/Calculator/calculate.php)

In my design have downpayment value. old design have single down payment now i have all loan separate down payment .i assign functionality its showing  default value of 3.5. how to change this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var min_jumbo_down_payment_1="<?php echo $min_jumbo_down_payment_1?>";
    var min_jumbo_down_payment_2="<?php echo $min_jumbo_down_payment_2?>";
    var min_fha_down_payment="<?php echo $min_fha_down_payment?>";
    var max_fha_loan="<?php echo $max_fha_loan?>";
    var max_va_loan="<?php echo $max_va_loan?>";


    function isNumeric(strString)
       //  check for valid numeric strings  
       {

       var strValidChars = "0123456789.-";
       var strChar;
       var blnResult = true;

       if (strString.length == 0) return false;

       //  test strString consists of valid characters listed above
       for (i = 0; i < strString.length && blnResult == true; i++)
          {
          strChar = strString.charAt(i);
          if (strValidChars.indexOf(strChar) == -1)
             {
              blnResult = false;
             }
          }
       return blnResult;
       }

    function ficoChanged()
    {
      //setDownPayment();

      getMIP("hh");

    }

    function loanTypeChanged()
    {

      setDownPayment();
      getMIP("loantype"); //it must be set to loantype 
     alert(loantype);
    }

    //always called by either change in loantype or change in fico 
    function setDownPayment()
    {

        if (userChangedDownPaymentPc_==true  || userChangedDownPaymentAmt_==true)
        {
            return;
        }
        //1. get selected loan type
        for (i=0;i<4;i++ )
        {
          if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['loantype'][i].checked==true)
            {
              var loantype_=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.loantype[i].value;
              break;
            }
        }

        if (loantype_=="usda" || loantype_=="va")
        {
            document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.downpaymentpc.value=0;
        }       
        else if (loantype_=="fha")
        {
            document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.downpaymentpc.value=min_fha_down_payment;
        }
        else if (loantype_=="jumbo")
        {
            var ficorange_=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['ficorange'].value;
            var arr=ficorange_.split("-");
            if(arr[1] >= 720)
            document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.downpaymentpc.value=min_jumbo_down_payment_1;
            else
            document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.downpaymentpc.value=min_jumbo_down_payment_2;
        }
    }


      function purchasePriceAmountChanged(fromuser_)
      {
          getMIP("hh");
          document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.monthlypayment.value="";
      }

      function monthlyPaymentChanged(fromuser_)
      {

          document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.purchaseprice.value="";
          document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.upfrontmippc.value="";
          document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.upfrontmipamt.value="";
          document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.monthlymippc.value="";
          document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.monthlymipamt.value="";
          document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.ssmonthlymippc.value="";
          document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.ssmonthlymipamt.value="";

      }

      function downPaymentAmountChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
      {
          alert("ok");
        if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.downpaymentamt.value!="")
        {
         document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.downpaymentpc.value="";         
         getMIP("hh");
        }
      }

      function downPaymentPcChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
      {

       alert("ok 1");
        if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.downpaymentpc.value!="")
        {
             alert("ok 2");
         document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.downpaymentamt.value="";         
         getMIP("hh");

        }
      }

     //   todo : CHANGE IT, ITS NOT WORKING ANYMORE
      function getLoanAmount()
      {
        var purchaseprice_=0;
        var downpayment_=0;
        var loanamount_=-1;
        var hasloan=false;
        if(document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.downpaymentamt.value!="")
          {
            downpayment_=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.downpaymentamt.value;
          }
        else
          {
              hasloan=true;
          }
        if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.purchaseprice.value!="")
          {
             purchaseprice_=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.purchaseprice.value;
          }
        else
          {
            hasloan=true;
          }

       if (hasloan==false)
          {
            loanamount_= purchaseprice_ - downpayment_ ;
          }

          return loanamount_;
      }


      function getPurchasePrice()
      {
         if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.purchaseprice.value!="")
          {
             purchaseprice_=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.purchaseprice.value;
          }
          else
          {
             purchaseprice_=-1;
          }
        return purchaseprice_;
      }

      function upfrontMIPPcChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) else false
      {

          alert("ok");
        userChangedUpfrontMIP=fromuser_;
        if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.upfrontmippc.value !="")
          {
           document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.upfrontmipamt.value="";
          }
      }

      function upfrontMIPAmountChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
      {
         userChangedUpfrontMIP=fromuser_;
         if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.upfrontmipamt.value !="")
          {
           document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.upfrontmippc.value="";
          }
      }

      function monthlyMIPPcChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) else false
      {
         userChangedMonthlyMIP=fromuser_;
         if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.monthlymippc.value !="")
          {
           document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.monthlymipamt.value="";
          }
      }

      function monthlyMIPAmountChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
      {
         userChangedMonthlyMIP=fromuser_;
         if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.monthlymipamt.value !="")
          {
           document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.monthlymippc.value="";
          }
      }

      function ssmonthlyMIPPcChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) else false
      {
         userChangedSSMonthlyMIP=fromuser_;
         if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.ssmonthlymippc.value !="")
          {
           document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.ssmonthlymipamt.value="";
          }
      }

      function ssmonthlyMIPAmountChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
      {
         userChangedSSMonthlyMIP=fromuser_;
         if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.ssmonthlymipamt.value !="")
          {
           document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.ssmonthlymippc.value="";
          }
      }

     function propertyTaxPcChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
      {
        if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.propertytaxpc.value!="")
        {
         document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.propertytaxamt.value="";
        }
      }


     function propertyTaxAmountChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
      { 
        if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.propertytaxamt.value!="")
        {
         document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.propertytaxpc.value="";
        }
      }

     function hazardInsurancePcChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
      {
        if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.hazardinsurancepc.value!="")
        {
         document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.hazardinsuranceamt.value="";
        }
      }

     function hazardInsuranceAmountChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
      { 
        if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.hazardinsuranceamt.value!="")
        {
         document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.hazardinsurancepc.value="";
        }
      }

     function melloRoosAmountChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
      { 
        if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.melloroosfeeamt.value!="")
        {
         document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.melloroosfeepc.value="";
        }
      }  

     function melloRoosPcChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
      { 
        if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.melloroosfeepc.value!="")
        {
         document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.melloroosfeeamt.value="";
        }
      }     

     function other1PcChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
      { 
        if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other1pc.value!="")
        {
         document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other1amt.value="";
        }
      } 

     function other1AmountChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
      { 
        if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other1amt.value!="")
        {
         document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other1pc.value="";
        }
      }       

     function other2PcChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
      { 
        if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other2pc.value!="")
        {
         document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other2amt.value="";
        }
      } 

     function other2AmountChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
      { 
        if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other2amt.value!="")
        {
         document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other2pc.value="";
        }
      }

     function other3PcChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
      { 
        if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other3pc.value!="")
        {
         document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other3amt.value="";
        }
      } 

     function other3AmountChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
      { 
        if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other3amt.value!="")
        {
         document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other3pc.value="";
        }
      }

      function secondsChanged()
      {
        getMIP("hh");
      }
```

i have down payment code Looks Like new design

```
<div class="col-md-2 padding-Zero" >
<input name="downpaymentpc" id="downpaymentpc" type="text" class="txt" size="8"  maxlength="8" onChange="javascript:downPaymentPcChanged(true);" value="<?php echo $min_fha_down_payment;?>" />
 </div>
```

this code assign in  new design four  loan payment down payment field ..
 but this all input fields  showing default value 3.5..

my old design code downpayment

```
     <td>Down payment $</td>
     <td> <input name="downpaymentpc" id="downpaymentpc" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" onChange="javascript:downPaymentPcChanged(true);" value="<?php echo $min_fha_down_payment;?>" />%</td>
     <td colspan="2">Or $ <input name="downpaymentamt" id="downpaymentamt" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" onChange="javascript:downPaymentAmountChanged(true);"  />   </td>
  </tr>
```

in my old design working good. same functionality Not Working new design ? any idea about this ?